# Releasing strain relief coupling

Tags: electrical, cables

I need to wire a new power cord into my garage door opener.

This cable gland has to release the existing wire.

https://imgur.com/gallery/xlwH05n

[image]

It seems like I can squeeze the tab in the bottom but it still won’t come off.

Comment: "gland"? Not a usage I've seen before. I'd call that a strain relief insert.

Comment: That is a strain relief. A cable gland is a different thing.

Comment: Thanks. Eager to get the terminology right.

Comment: I got it off, but it was really tricky. I had to open it by using a slot in the front while holding the bottom. It's a Heyco® RDD Lockit™ Strain Relief Bushing.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need a pair of channel-lock pliers:
[image]
<sub>Random Amazon Example</sub>

Use them to squeeze the ridged piece that's sticking out the side of the strain relief insert:
[image]
The whole insert should now be able to pop up through the hole in the housing.

Once it's out, you should be able to release the cable clamp:
[image]
You may need to lever it with a small flat screwdriver.

After that the cable should be loose and you can replace it.
Reverse the operation to re-install the cable & strain relief back into the hole in the housing.

Comment: ok -- I'm able to get the coupling 80% out, but there is a tab on the left that I can't move. this is the OEM part: https://www.northshorecommercialdoor.com/genie-39346rs-power-cord.html/

Comment: Can you use the channel locks to squeeze it out the rest of the way?  Basically squeeze between the flat part of the strain relief and the other side of the sheet metal?  May need to shift from left to right to eke it out bit by bit.

Answer (score 2):

You have to squeeze it with some adjustable pliers, Channellocks, and then pull down. It is a tight fit. You'll need to squeeze it and push it up to install the new cord.